# How to sum items of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I want to show the total credits of the array but cant seem to get the total number to show up correctly.

```
  const totalAvailableCredits = [credits].reduce((credits, availableCredits) => {
    return availableCredits + credits;
  }, 0);
```

When I console.log credits it does show up but is inaccurate on the actual site:

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{creditId: 71, expiresOn: '2023-09-26T14:33:58Z', available: 10, createdOn: '2022-09-26T14:33:58Z'}
1
:
{creditId: 265, expiresOn: '2023-10-26T18:05:54Z', available: 2, createdOn: '2022-10-26T18:05:54Z'}
length
:
2
[[Prototype]]
:
Array

Comment: Could you provide some more info about what exactly you are trying to do and what is not working correclty?

Comment: Show where you call `totalCredits`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By wrapping `credits` in square brackets you're creating a new array containing a single item (credits), so your reduce function is always going to return `credits + 0`. And using the same name for two different variables creates unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all numbers in an array you can just use  [array-sum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-sum) in node or react projects